# Phonegap 2.9 android - InAppBrowser - <input type="file"> not working

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, file-upload, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a small phonegap app for android.

One button launches a website I built with jquery mobile 1.3.

I am opening the page using:

```
 websiteRef=window.open('https://'+webstage+'.mysite.org/mobile?language_id=2', '_blank', 'location=no' );
```

The website works fine. But when I hit one page that allows for uploading a file using the following markup:

```
 <input type="file" name="upload" value="file" data-inline="true" style="min-width:100px;"/>
```

It does not work. It does not even show a file selection dialog (gallery, etc.). The button is completely without function and reaction.

Opening the exact same page using the android internet browser works fine. At the exact same page I can choose e. g. from Gallery and other file selection methods and the upload works.

Since this is an external website, all the references to phonegap PLUGINs like Android File UPloader appear to be of no help for me.

Answer (score 1):

input type file is not supported by androids webview (it works on iOS though). if you want to browse your gallery, you need to use the [camera api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) to retrieve the URI and then, if you want to upload it somewhere > use the [file api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File).

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option since the webSite must be available to everyone not only users of my app. I was just calling the public page to enable online viewing. Users wanted to add photos and this is not working when viewing the page with phonegaps inapp browser. Sad - but there seems to be no way to do it.

Comment: if you are the author of whole website and can mess around a little bit with the code, there is no problem then, I just had the same situation.

Comment: @Marcin it is good to know iOS can support input type file, do you have a reference to further explain this? i usually thought the behavior of input type file is implemented by Browser, since webview is not a full browser, it may not have a default implementation for this. didn't realize this is different behavior btw two WebViews (Android vs iOS)

Comment: I believe there is no rational explanation ;) as there are some differences in handling CSS, so there may be differences in whole webview functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

for media elements (like audio mp3), use cordova-pluin-mediapicker

```
window.plugins.mediapicker.getAudio(success,error,false,false," ");

function success(data)
{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
function error(e)
{
  console.log(e);
}
```

more info here

https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-mediapicker