# input type file is not supported in android phonegap app with accept='image/*;capture=camera' option

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, camera

I have created an app using phonegap which require upload image from gallery,camera etc.

I am using

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*;capture=camera' />
```

but it doesnt support on android it only shows me gallery not camera option while in iphone it works for camera but after selecting captured camera image it refresh the app.

Please help me if I am doing any mistake.

Thanks,
Vijay Barnwal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760334/phonegap-2-9-android-inappbrowser-input-type-file-not-working/17763628#17763628 its been answered

Answer (score 1):

Bro I guess the syntax mistake in the code you have given it should have been

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' capture='camera' />
```

instead of

```
  <input type='file' accept='image/*;capture=camera' />
```